# Как сравнить данные из базы данных с csv файлом на Python?

Tags: python, база-данных, csv

У меня есть большая база данных и несколко парсеров, парсеры делают CSV файлы каждый день и их нужно добовлять в базу данных, проблема в том, что большая часть данных будет та же самая, что выдаст ошибку.

Мне нужно сравнить CSV файил с данными в бд и если в CSV файле будет что то новое, для базы данных, добавить эти данные в новый CSV файл, который затем будет добовляться в бд(соотвественно без ошибок. потому что данные не повторяются)

Как можно сравнить их и выделить новые только в CSV файле?

Пока остановился на pandas и чтению таблицы:

```
df1 = pd.read_sql_table('auto', engine)
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'csv\ss.csv')
```

PS. Знаю про метод с временной таблицей в бд, но он мне не подходит

Пример части из БД:

```
ID   make     model  year
600  Toyota   Prius  2016
610  Toyota   Prius  2014
728  BMW      M5     2016
789  Ford     F-150  2016
823  Toyota   Auris  2016
```

Пример CSV файла:

```
ID   make     model  year
712  Toyota   Prius  2012
728  BMW      M5     2016
789  Ford     F-150  2016
```

То есть я хочу сделать, что бы csv файл с отличаеми попала только строка "712  Toyota   Prius  2012"

Comment: Почему бы вам не проверять есть ли занчение в бд, и потом добавлять если его нет?

Comment: @ProgerOffline Я был бы рад, если вы поделитесь как это делать, так как у меня ещё очень мало опыта и не знаю, что для этого нужно использовать.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос выше добавив пример данных из бд и сsv файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как можно сравнить их и выделить новые только в CSV файле?

если у вас датафреймы то выделить можно как-то так:

```
df2[~df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])]

>>> out
'''
    ID    make  model  year
0  712  Toyota  Prius  2012
```

Comment: Наверное только на ID маловато опираться? Может там информация изменена?

Comment: @СергейКох может и так, но в примере у автора все ID уникальные

Comment: @SergFSM, Спасибо за Ваш ответ, вроде как все правильно работает, остается разобраиться, как разницу выводить в новый csv файл
Так же вопрос, если сравнивать надо не только ID нужно все таки будет, остальные элементы можно же добавить через запятую?

Comment: @СергейКох нет, через запятую нельзя, но можно попробовать такой способ `df2[~df2.apply(tuple,axis=1).isin(list(map(tuple,df1.values)))]`, хотя эффективность этого способа я не берусь судить. попробуйте оформить это новым вопросом, возможно вам предложат способ поинтересней.